# Converting string using bash

Tags: bash, grep

I want to convert the output of command:

```
dmidecode -s system-serial-number
```

which is a string looking like this:

```
VMware-56 4d ad 01 22 5a 73 c2-89 ce 3f d8 ba d6 e4 0c
```

to:

```
564dad01-225a-73c2-89ce-3fd8bad6e40c
```

I suspect I need to first of all extract all letters and numbers after the "VMware-" part at that start and then insert "-" at the known positions after character 10, 14, 18, 22.

To try the first extraction I have tried:

```
$ echo `dmidecode -s system-serial-number | grep -oE '(VMware-)?[a0-Z9]'`
VMware-5 6 4 d a d 0 1 2 2 5 a 7 3 c 2 8 9 c e 3 f d 8 b a d 6 e 4 0 c
```

However this isn't going the right way.

EDIT:

This gets me to a single log string however it's not elegant:

```
$ echo `dmidecode -s system-serial-number | sed -s "s/VMware-//" | sed -s "s/-//" | sed -s "s/ //g"` 
564dad01225a73c289ce3fd8bad6e40c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
dmidecode -s system-serial-number | 
    sed -E 's/VMware-//;
            s/ +//g;
            s/(.)/\1-/8;
            s/(.)/\1-/13;
            s/(.)/\1-/23'
```

Comment: `\s` is GNU SED only. Replace `s/\s+//g;` with `s/ +//g;` for POSIX SED...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bash [sub string extraction](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
$ s="VMware-56 4d ad 01 22 5a 73 c2-89 ce 3f d8 ba d6 e4 0c"
$ s1=$(echo "${s:7}" | tr -d '[:space:]')
$ echo "${s1:0:8}-${s1:8:4}-${s1:12:9}-${s1:21}"
564dad01-225a-73c2-89ce-3fd8bad6e40c
```

Or, built-ins only (ie, no `tr`):

```
$ s1=${s:7}
$ s1="${s1// /}"
$ echo "${s1:0:8}-${s1:8:4}-${s1:12:9}-${s1:21}"
```

Comment: You can use only builtins with this parameter expansion to remove spaces: `echo "${s// /}"`